# Execution halted issue

Tags: r

[image]

I can not solve that issue..
when I click on the knit in Rstudio, the below message showed in the console every time..

"Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
cannot open file './experience.Rmd': No such file or directory
Execution halted."

how can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: The error message is clear.  The file you are attempting to read (presumably `./experience.Rmd`, but we cannot be sure because your example is not reproducible), either (a) does not exist or (b) is not located where you think it is.  A third option is (c) your working directory is not where you think it is.  Add `getwd()` and `normalizePath("./experience.Rmd")` to your script and compare the output to what you think it should be.  Alternatively, change your relative path to an absolute path.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You seem to be editing a file named `academic-cv.Rmd`. Somewhere in the code it must make a reference to a different file named `experience.Rmd`. That file cannot be found. Are you sure it exists? Is it in the same place as the other Rmd?